# Python - group files by modified date [hour]

Tags: python

I'm using the following script to grab all the files in a directory, then filtering them based on their modified date.

```
dir = '/tmp/whatever'
dir_files = os.listdir(dir)
dir_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.stat(os.path.join(dir, x)).st_mtime)
files = []
for f in dir_files:
    t = os.path.getmtime(dir + '/' + f)
    c = os.path.getctime(dir + '/' + f)
    mod_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    created_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c)
    if mod_time >= form.cleaned_data['start'].replace(tzinfo=None) and mod_time <= form.cleaned_data['end'].replace(tzinfo=None):
         files.append(f)
return by_hour
```

I'm need to go one step further and group the files by the hour in which they where modified. Does anyone know how to do this off the top of their head?

UPDATE: I'd like to have them in a dictionary ({date,hour,files})

**UPDATED:** 
Thanks for all your replies!. I tried using the response from david, but when I output the result it looks like below (ie. it's breaking up the filename):

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 15, 0): ['2', '8', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '5', '1', '8', '4', '3', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '2', '9', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '5', '2', '0', '2', '4', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '3', '0', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '5', '3', '8', '5', '9', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '3', '1', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '5', '4', '1', '2', '4', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '3', '2', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '5', '5', '3', '1', '0', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '3', '3', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '5', '5', '5', '5', '8', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i'], datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 19, 0): ['6', '1', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '9', '0', '1', '1', '8', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '6', '2', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '9', '0', '6', '3', '1', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '6', '3', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '9', '1', '4', '1', '5', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i', '6', '4', '-', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '9', '1', '9', '2', '2', '3', '3', '.', 'a', 'v', 'i']})
```

I was hoping to get it to store the complete file names. Also how would I loop over it and grab the files in each hour and the hour they belong to?

I managed to sort the above out by just changing it to append. However it's not sorted from  the oldest hour to the most recent.

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: What do you mean by "group them"? Do you want to construct a list or dictionary dividing the files?

Comment: yep a dictionary, check updated question

Comment: .. .its not related to `django`; remove its tag.

Comment: removed django tag as per request

Comment: `itertools.groupby` will be your best bet remember to sort the list of files before using group by.

Comment: Your dictionary definition `{date,hour,files}` is unclear. Do you want it to look like `{(date, hour): files}`? Would it be acceptable (as in my answer below) to have a `datetime` object rounded to the hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can round a `datetime` object to the nearest hour with the line:

```
mod_hour = datetime.datetime(*mod_time.timetuple()[:4])
```

(This is because `mod_time.timetuple()[:4]` returns a tuple like `(2013, 1, 8, 21`). Thus, using a `collections.defaultdict` to keep a dictionary of lists:

```
import collections

by_hour = collections.defaultdict(list)
for f in dir_files:
    t = os.path.getmtime(dir + '/' + f)
    mod_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    mod_hour = datetime.datetime(*mod_time.timetuple()[:4])
    # for example, (2013, 1, 8, 21)
    by_hour[mod_hour].append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, datetime, operator
dir = "Your_dir_path"
by_hour =sorted([(f,datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir , f)))) for f in os.listdir(dir)],key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

above code will give sorting based on year-->month-->day-->hour-->min-->sec format.

Answer (score 0):

Building on David's excellent answer, you can use itertools.groupby to simplify the work a little bit:

```
import os, itertools, datetime

dir = '/tmp/whatever'
mtime = lambda f : datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dir + '/' + f))
mtime_hour = lambda f: datetime.datetime(*mtime(f).timetuple()[:4])
dir_files = sorted(os.listdir(dir), key=mtime)
dir_files = filter(lambda f: datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,4) <   mtime(f) < datetime.datetime(2012,12,1,4), dir_files) 
by_hour = dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(dir_files, key=mtime_hour)) #python 2.6
#by_hour = {k:list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(dir_files, key=mtime_hour)} #python 2.7
```

Comment: I get a Syntax error on the last line when i use this :( 
Also I can't filter by a date range as per my question.

Comment: I made 2 changes: removed the dict comprehension to work with python < 2.7, and added a filter step as requested. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Build entries lazily, Use UTC timezone, read modification time only once:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

HOUR = 3600 # seconds in an hour
dirpath = "/path/to/dir"
start, end = datetime(...), datetime(...)

# get full paths for all entries in dirpath
entries = (os.path.join(dirpath, name) for name in os.listdir(dirpath))
# add modification time truncated to hour
def date_and_hour(path):
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path) // HOUR * HOUR)
entries = ((date_and_hour(path), path) for path in entries)
# filter by date range: [start, end)
entries = ((mtime, path) for mtime, path in entries if start <= mtime < end)
# group by hour
result = defaultdict(list)
for dt, path in entries:
    result[dt].append(path)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dict(result))
```